# CPU Normal Voltages

Tags: memory, cpu, temperature

I have the following configuration in my PC: i5 8400, MSI B360 Gaming Plus, 16GB DDR4, GTX1050Ti. 
I am wondering what are the normal voltages for this CPU and if I can modify them in order for my CPU to work at a cooler temperature ? 
My current temperatures are: 28-50 C when I have nothing opened on my desktop, only the HWMonitor (and the background processes), and 63C (maximum) under Intel Burn Test. I am using a Hyper 212 Evo CPU cooler. The room temperature is about 22C. Under Intel Burn Test, the maximum core voltage is about 1.185V.

Comment: These temperatures look completely normal to me, why do you want to lower them?

Comment: Reducing the CPU voltage without underclocking the CPU will only end up in a lot of system crashes.

Comment: Developer of Throttlestop suggests for your CPU *"-125 mV is typical. -145 mV is probably too aggressive."* on reddit [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/bw2y81/problems_with_throttlestop_settings/) but you'd have to test it.